# *Basic* JavaFX TableView of Single String Column

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create an incredibly simple JavaFX TableView: 1 column of Strings.  I have an Array which I would like to visualize:

```
String[] acronyms = {"Foo", "Bar"};
```

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) presumes some datatype to fill multiple columns (e.g. Person, Book, etc.).  I am going much more "hello world" than that: just displaying an Array of Strings.

Using scene builder I created an fxml file with the table & column:

```
<TableView fx:id="clientAcronymTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
 <columns>
  <TableColumn fx:id="clientAcronymColumn" prefWidth="199.0" text="Client Acronyms" />
 </columns>
  <columnResizePolicy>
     <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
  </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

I then "wire" these elements inside of my controller:

```
@FXML private TableView<String> clientAcronymTable;

@FXML private TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> clientAcronymColumn;
```

And inside my `Initializable::initialize` method I have:

```
clientAcronymTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(acronyms));
```

However, none of the Strings appear in the GUI.  I know *something* is happening because there are visible row lines displayed in the column, but they're all empty.

There are of course similar questions which don't really apply:

1. [Related to more than one column, not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033404/javafx-2-create-tableview-with-single-column)
2. [Creates a
   custom Row Class which seems like overkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211822/populating-a-tableview-with-strings)

So, my questions are:

**How do I make the Strings in my Array visible inside of the TableView**?

**How do I make the single column editable so the user can add more Strings**?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: you should use cellvaluefactory for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have the wrong type for your `TableColumn`. Since each row contains a `String` (not an `ObservableList<String>`), you need

```
@FXML private TableColumn<String, String> clientAcronymColumn;
```

And then you need a `cellValueFactory`, which tells each cell in the column how to get the value it displays from the row:

```
clientAcronymColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()));
```

As for adding more strings, you would typically have an external text field for the user to provide more:

```
// you can of course define the text field in FXML if you prefer...
TextField newAcronymTextField = new TextField();

newAcronymTextField.setOnAction(e -> {
    clientAcronymTable.getItems().add(newAcronymTextField.getText());
    newAcronymTextField.clear();
});
```

Comment: Do you know what the type of `cellData` is?

Comment: `cellData` is a`TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>`