# webEngine.getHistory() add in TableView

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have a code that assigns the historic in a ComboBox, but I needed within a Table!

Source

```
final ComboBox locationHistory = new ComboBox();
    final WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();
    history.getEntries().addListener(new 
        ListChangeListener<WebHistory.Entry>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends WebHistory.Entry> c) {
                c.next();
                for (WebHistory.Entry e : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                    locationHistory.getItems().add(e.getUrl());
                }
            }
    });
```

it was..

Answer (score 1):

You code will be the same about adding an item in the list. If you call your table "locationHistory", then

```
locationHistory.getItems().add(e.getUrl());
```

code will add items of type WebHistory.Entry in the table.

Now, you have another trouble :

You have a tableView, and you have a list of items in a table (getItems()). Each item corresponds to one line in table. To show content, so that parts of lines are separated into  columns, you have to add columns in a list of columns of table, and for each column add a cellValueFactory. Each value factory provides a possibility to extract info, needed to be shown in column, for each data item (it gets info about data item, and retuns description of info, which is to be shown in corresponding column for a corresponding item).

Further, read about how to add a cell value factory for a column here : [Cell factory in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519534/cell-factory-in-javafx)