# Populate combo box list dynamically for each row in javaFx table view

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-8

I have created a table view in java Fx, one of the columns in table view consists of 
ComboBoxTableCell.Please find below the code for table view

```
public class TabViewController {
    @FXML
    private TabPane cnfmTab;

    @FXML
    private TableView<TabVO> partsTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabVO, String> column1;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabVO, String> column2;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabVO, String> column3;

    private ObservableList<TabVO> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private ObservableList<String> column1List;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){

    tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(callDAO.getTableData(1));

    column1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getColumn1()));

    column1
        .setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<tabVO, String>, TableCell<tabVO, String>>() {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                ComboBoxTableCell cell = new ComboBoxTableCell(column1List){
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {


                    }
                };
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return cell;
            }
        });

    column1.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<tabVO, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<tabVO,String> t) {

                    };
                }
                );
    }

    partsTable.setItems(tableData);
}
```

Data object:

```
public class TabVO {


    private String column1; 

    private String column2; 

    private String column3;

    private ObservableList<String> column1List;


    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

In the above code each row of the table is of type TabVo.

In the table column1 is of type combo box. Right now the list for column1 combo box is populate by
'column1List' which is declared in 'TabViewController', because of which all the rows of the table view are populated
with the same drop down.

But i want the each row of the table to be populated with different list which is present in TabVo.

Can anyone please tell me how to access TabVo object and populate the combobox with the list present in TabVo?

Comment: How do I do this with just FXML? I have a factory, but i cannot pass it a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MVCE with use case described in the question:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class ComboBoxCellTableExample extends Application
{

    private final TableView<TabVo> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<TabVo> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new TabVo( "2222", "column2", FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList( "111", "2222", "3333" ) ),
                    new TabVo( "bbbb", "column2", FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList( "aaaa", "bbbb", "ccccc" ) ),
                    new TabVo( "6666", "column2", FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList( "444", "5555", "6666" ) ),
                    new TabVo( "7777", "column2", FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList( "7777", "8888", "99999" ) ),
                    new TabVo( "hhhh", "column2", FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList( "hhhh", "jjjj", "kkkkk" ) )
            );


    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage )
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene( new Group() );
        stage.setWidth( 450 );
        stage.setHeight( 550 );

        table.setEditable( true );
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>()
        {
            @Override
            public TableCell call( TableColumn p )
            {
                return new ComboBoxCell();
            }
        };

        TableColumn column1Col = new TableColumn( "Column 1" );
        column1Col.setMinWidth( 100 );
        column1Col.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<TabVo, String>( "column1" ) );
        column1Col.setCellFactory( cellFactory );
        column1Col.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TabVo, String>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle( TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TabVo, String> t )
                    {
                        (( TabVo ) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow() )).setColumn1( t.getNewValue() );
                    }
                }
        );

        TableColumn column2Col = new TableColumn( "Column 2" );
        column2Col.setMinWidth( 100 );
        column2Col.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<TabVo, String>( "column2" ) );
        column2Col.setCellFactory( TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn() );
        column2Col.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TabVo, String>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle( TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TabVo, String> t )
                    {
                        (( TabVo ) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow() )).setColumn2( t.getNewValue() );
                    }
                }
        );

        table.setItems( data );
        table.getColumns().addAll( column1Col, column2Col );

        (( Group ) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add( table );

        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }


    class ComboBoxCell extends TableCell<TabVo, String>
    {

        private ComboBox<String> comboBox;


        public ComboBoxCell()
        {
            comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        }


        @Override
        public void startEdit()
        {
            if ( !isEmpty() )
            {
                super.startEdit();

                comboBox.setItems( getTableView().getItems().get( getIndex() ).getColumn1List() );
                comboBox.getSelectionModel().select( getItem() );

                comboBox.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue )
                    {
                        if ( !newValue )
                        {
                            commitEdit( comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() );
                        }
                    }
                } );

                setText( null );
                setGraphic( comboBox );
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void cancelEdit()
        {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText( ( String ) getItem() );
            setGraphic( null );
        }


        @Override
        public void updateItem( String item, boolean empty )
        {
            super.updateItem( item, empty );

            if ( empty )
            {
                setText( null );
                setGraphic( null );
            }
            else
            {
                if ( isEditing() )
                {
                    setText( null );
                    setGraphic( comboBox );
                }
                else
                {
                    setText( getItem() );
                    setGraphic( null );
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }


    public static class TabVo
    {

        private String column1;
        private String column2;

        private ObservableList<String> column1List;


        private TabVo( String column1, String column2, ObservableList<String> column1List )
        {
            this.column1 = column1;
            this.column2 = column2;
            this.column1List = column1List;
        }


        public String getColumn1()
        {
            return column1;
        }


        public void setColumn1( String column1 )
        {
            this.column1 = column1;
        }


        public String getColumn2()
        {
            return column2;
        }


        public void setColumn2( String column2 )
        {
            this.column2 = column2;
        }


        public ObservableList<String> getColumn1List()
        {
            return column1List;
        }


        public void setColumn1List( ObservableList<String> column1List )
        {
            this.column1List = column1List;
        }

    }

}
```

First column uses combobox in edit mode, while the second column uses default factory for textfields.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But when i click the drop down, the `setOnEditCommit` listener is invoked only once during initial selection. It is not invoked if i try to select other values in the drop down.

Comment: @SyedAmmar, after changing the value from combobox, the cell is still in edit mode, you need to focus out from cell, so the combobox.focusProperty can commitEdit. Alternatively you can put commitEdit() on combobox item changeListener if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a CellValueFactory for the cell. This factory defines the values that will be shown in the column by using the current value of the table item list for the given row. See this link: [Cell factory in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519534/cell-factory-in-javafx)

Comment: The `setCellValueFactory` for TableColumn accepts `Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<T>> value`. I was just wondering if an `ObservableList<T>` can be type-casted/wrapped to `ObservableValue<T>`?